# Duplicate answer to duplicate question deleted - Have improved answer - please reconsider

Tags: discussion, specific-question

This question:
[Open VPN calling a script: Unrecognized option: [AF_INET]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/400905/open-vpn-calling-a-script-unrecognized-option-af-inet)

is technically a duplicate of this question:
[curl not receiving JSON in open vpn](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401329/curl-not-receiving-json-in-open-vpn/401597#401597)

Albeit slightly reworded, the question is **exactly** the same.

Also asked here:
https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=25114

My ANSWER to the the FIRST Link here has been unreasonably deleted by a moderator.  If the same Question is asked (even if it is reworded) then the same CORRECT Answer applies.

If you want to delete a **duplicate Question** then please do, but *please* do not delete a **Correct Answer** to that duplicate Question.  Thanks

**EDIT**: Is it *really* necessary to down vote a legitimate question ?
(Especially when your own support documentation recommended I ask this question on meta-*)

For the record; I find Stack-Exchange to be ***unreasonably heavy handed*** when it comes to dealing with users that don't spend there entire life on one website.

I have spent time reading the support documentation and have also provided answers to questions and put time and effort into doing things right.  And yet at every possible turn somebody here gets some twisted pleasure out of putting new users down.

I don't want my question up voted .. but there is absolutely *no positive return* to down voting it just because you want to .. the dictionary would define such actions as "spiteful" ..

Comment: If it is a duplicate, flag as a duplicate. Don't spam the same answer to multiple questions. We prefer to close as duplicates instead.

Comment: In future I will

Answer (score 3):

Your answer was deleted because it was exactly the same as the answer you'd already given elsewhere. We try to avoid repeating information.

You have since edited the answer so that it isn't the same and adds more information. That's great, and I have undeleted it.

In future, if you find examples like this, flag the question as a duplicate instead of posting identical answers. The system detects 100% identical answers and automatically flags them for moderator attention.

Comment: Thanks .. I would also consider either merging the two original questions or deleting the one with least info.  The questions are for the same problem and is of no real help to anybody except the OP.